# Limit of sequence 2

Tags: limits

I have to examine limit of the following sequence $a_n = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(2 - \frac{1}{k})^k}}$. I only know that $a_n \le \sqrt[n]{n2^n}$ but it's not enough to use squeeze theorem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$ \sum_{k=1}^n (2 - \frac 1k)^k \ge  (2 - \frac 1n)^n$$
so that 
$$\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n (2 - \frac 1k)^k} \ge 2 - \frac 1n.$$

Comment: Why $\sum_{k=1}^n (2 - \frac 1k)^k \ge  (2 - \frac 1n)^n$?

Comment: For the same reason that $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 \ge 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $1\le k\le n$ then
$$
\Bigl(2-\frac1n\Bigr)^k\le \Bigl(2-\frac1k\Bigr)^k\le2^k.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(2-\frac1k\Bigr)^k\le\sum_{k=1}^n2^k\le2^{n+1}
$$
and if $n\ge2$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(2-\frac1k\Bigr)^k\ge\sum_{k=1}^n\Bigl(2-\frac1n\Bigr)^k=\frac{(2-1/n)^{n+1}-(2-1/n)}{1-1/n}\ge\Bigl(2-\frac1n\Bigr)^{n+1}.
$$